# Symfony route url (variable joined to a literal)

Tags: symfony1, url-routing, symfony-1.4

I'd like to generate an URL like this one:

```
/MyCategory/MySubCategory/page2.html
```

I have tried to do it this way:

```
my_route: 
url: /:variable1/:variable2/literal:variable3.html
```

But Symfony outputs this:

```
/MyCategory/MySubCategory/page:variable3.html
```

I'm using Symfony 1.4.1

How could I solve this?

Comment: Please show your `url_for()` or smth relative to this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
my_route: 
  url: /:variable1/:variable2/:variable3
  param: { module: mymodule, action: myaction }
```

in SF_APP/config/factories.yml:

```
prod:
  routing:
    param:
      suffix: .html
```

Usage:

```
<?php echo url_for('my_route', array('variable1'=>'news', 'variable2'=>'sports', 'variable3'=>'page2'));?>
```

So it should produce:

```
/news/sports/page2.html
```

Comment: Well, I think I was unclear in my question. The literal was 'page', and variable3 is the page number.

But I solved it from a different point of view. I used the entire "page2" as a variable, as you suggested, and then in the controller I separated "page" from "2".

Thanks anyway.